# C#: Merge two objects based on common identifier?

Tags: c#, sorting, inner-classes

I have a POCO class with nested classes in it defined as such:

```
class Company 
{  
   string CompanyName { get; set; }
   List<Server> Servers { get; set; }
}

class Server 
{
   int ServerId { get; set;}
   string ServerName { get; set; }
   List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

class User
{
   string FirstName { get; set; }
   string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I had this instantiated with the following data:

```
CompanyName = "Company A";
Servers =    
   ServerId = 134;
   ServerName = HOST01;
   Users =
      FirstName = "John";
      LastName = "Smith";
      FirstName = "Bob";
      LastName = "Jones";

   ServerId = 232;
   ServerName = HOST31;
   Users = 
      FirstName = "Michael";
      LastName = "Stevens";

   ServerId = 134;
   ServerName = HOST01;
   Users =
      FirstName = "Larry";
      LastName = "Edwards";
      FirstName = "Craig";
      LastName = "White";
```

How would I go about merging all the users together, based on a matching "ServerId" property? Basically, how could I transform it to this?

```
CompanyName = "Company A";
Servers =    
   ServerId = 134;
   ServerName = HOST01;
   Users =
      FirstName = "John";
      LastName = "Smith";
      FirstName = "Bob";
      LastName = "Jones";
      FirstName = "Larry";
      LastName = "Edwards";
      FirstName = "Craig";
      LastName = "White"; 

   ServerId = 232;
   ServerName = HOST31;
   Users = 
      FirstName = "Michael";
      LastName = "Stevens";
```

Comment: Can the same user exist in multiple "Servers" and/or Companies?

Comment: Yes. Users can span across servers and companies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq`, like the following code :

1 - get the distinct servers, by id and name :

```
List<Server> distinctServers = company.Servers
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.ServerId, s.ServerName })
    .Select(s => new Server
    {
        ServerId = s.Key.ServerId,
        ServerName = s.Key.ServerName,
        Users = s.SelectMany(x => x.Users).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

2 - construct a new company or use the old:

```
Company result = new Company
{
    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
    Servers = distinctServers
};
// or   
company.Servers = distinctServers;
```

If you have list of companies, you can use the same code inside `select` function:

```
List<Company> companies = new List<Company> { company };
List<Company> companiesWithDistinctServers = companies
    .Select(c => new Company
    {
        CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
        Servers = c.Servers.GroupBy(s => new { s.ServerId, s.ServerName })
            .Select(s => new Server
            {
                ServerId = s.Key.ServerId,
                ServerName = s.Key.ServerName,
                Users = s.SelectMany(x => x.Users).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

i hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ `GroupBy` to group on `ServerId`, and assuming that servers with the same id also have the same name.

```
var grouped = Companies // IEnumerable<Company>
    .Select(c => new Company
    {
        CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
        Servers = c.Servers
            .GroupBy(s => s.ServerId)
            .Select(grp => new Server
            {
                ServerId = grp.Key,
                ServerName = grp.First().ServerName,
                Users = grp.SelectMany(s => s.Users)).ToList()
            })
    });
```